# Cannot Find mysqli Class in PHP7 Installation on Windows

Tags: php, mysqli

I downloaded and installed php7 from: http://windows.php.net/qa/#php-7.0-ts-VC14-x64

The php codes are running fine.
I am not able to connect database using 'mysqli' Class. It says

> Class 'mysqli' not found

I've uncommented `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in php.ini file.
Did I miss anything while installing php7.

Comment: Did you install a MySQL Server as well as PHP?

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I solved the issue, it was a silly mistake. I did not set the `extension_dir`, now I set it to `extension_dir = "C:\php7\ext"` and its working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @gskhanal, can you please post this as an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted? This helps tidy up the unanswered questions list and will also give you awesome-stackoverflow-points ;)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue and I tried setting the extension_dir to the absolute path. I tried with backslashes and forward slashes. None works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the issue, it was a silly mistake. The `extension_dir` was not set. I set it to `extension_dir = "C:\php7\ext"` and its working fine.

Comment: sorry!! but where to set that extension or extension_dir, please give some detail

Comment: @Pradeep, you need to set that in your php.ini file.